# How not to persist model entities to the database spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

This is my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MYTABLE")
public class MyTable {

    Integer errCode; 

    String errorText;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;
    ...
}
```

There are some fields that I want to persist to the database like id but there are some I don't want to like errCode and errText. Are there any annotations to not have them persist? Is it @Transient that I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The annotation you are looking for is @Transient.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add **@Transient** to all the getters for the fields that you do not wish to persist. These are usually for helper methods. I would suggest that you might not want to keep the error code and text in a class that you're attempting to persist. Maybe build another object that uses this class and provides the **errCode** and **errorText**. As sometimes Entities can get messy if there are a load of **@Transient** methods.